# Laravel 10 jerstream - redirect back doesn't work

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

I am using Laravel 10 with PHP 8.1

The issue that redirect back is not working, it's redirecting me to home only.

even in the core functions i need to manipulate it like login i added:

```
throw ValidationException::withMessages([
    'email' => [trans('auth.failed')],
])->redirectTo('login');
```

so I need to specify every route in the project and overwrite the packages controllers.

on my local host i use PHP 8.2 and its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a referrer header issue from nginx, I solved it by adding this line to configuration

```
  add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade";
```